# Is it possible to add stroke to text in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to add black stroke to text in ffmpeg. Is it possible?

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=arialuni.ttf:textfile=z1.txt : x=0/2:y=h-t*13:fontcolor=white:fontsize=35:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=10:shadowy=10" -shortest -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -g 160 -b:v 4000k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset superfast output1.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - set the `borderw` option in your `drawtext` filter to set the width of the stroke you want.

`bordercolor` can be used to set the colour, but defaults to black so you don't need to set it for your use case.

For example, the command in the OP could become:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=arialuni.ttf:textfile=z1.txt : x=0/2:y=h-t*13:fontcolor=white:fontsize=35:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=10:shadowy=10:bordercolor=black:borderw=3" -shortest -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -g 160 -b:v 4000k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset superfast output1.mp4
```

See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1 for documentation.

Comment: I do not understand. can you help me a little more carefully?

Comment: You just add the stated options to the drawtext options you already have. I have updated the answer with how to amend your original command.